# Having issues getting Wine installed on my mac (Lion)

Tags: macos, macports, wine

I'm following this guide:  http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/#part-1

I've attached my main.log file, but this is the error I get:

```
ct-MacBook-Air:~ user$ sudo port install wine
--->  Computing dependencies for wine
--->  Dependencies to be installed: gst-plugins-base gnome-vfs gconf gtk2 pango shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto intltool p5.12-getopt-long p5.12-pathtools p5.12-scalar-list-utils p5.12-xml-parser orbit2 gtk-doc docbook-xml docbook-xml-4.1.2 docbook-xml-4.2 xmlcatmgr docbook-xml-4.3 docbook-xml-4.4 docbook-xml-4.5 docbook-xml-5.0 docbook-xsl gnome-doc-utils iso-codes libxslt py27-libxml2 rarian libidl policykit eggdbus gnome-mime-data gstreamer bison m4 flex gzip texinfo libtheora libvorbis libogg orc xorg-libice xorg-libsm lcms mesa xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libXxf86vm xorg-xf86vidmodeproto
--->  Fetching archive for pango
Error: org.macports.archivefetch for port pango returned: cairo must be installed without +x11.
Error: Failed to install pango
Please see the log file for port pango for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_pango/pango/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gst-plugins-base gnome-vfs gconf gtk2 pango shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto intltool p5.12-getopt-long p5.12-pathtools p5.12-scalar-list-utils p5.12-xml-parser orbit2 gtk-doc docbook-xml docbook-xml-4.1.2 docbook-xml-4.2 xmlcatmgr docbook-xml-4.3 docbook-xml-4.4 docbook-xml-4.5 docbook-xml-5.0 docbook-xsl gnome-doc-utils iso-codes libxslt py27-libxml2 rarian libidl policykit eggdbus gnome-mime-data gstreamer bison m4 flex gzip texinfo libtheora libvorbis libogg orc xorg-libice xorg-libsm lcms mesa xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libXxf86vm xorg-xf86vidmodeproto
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port wine failed
```

From the guide, I've tried:

```
$ sudo port -v selfupdate
$ sudo port upgrade outdated
```

But that didn't seem to help any. Is there anything else I should try or check?

---

## main.log

```
version:1
:debug:main Attempting ln -sf /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_pango/pango/work /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/x11/pango/work
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (pango)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch archivefetch phase started at Sat Feb 16 21:22:50 EST 2013
:msg:archivefetch --->  Fetching archive for pango
:debug:archivefetch Executing proc-pre-org.macports.archivefetch-archivefetch-0
:debug:archivefetch cairo is installed with the following variants: +universal+x11
:debug:archivefetch   required: , forbidden: quartz
:debug:archivefetch   accepted
:debug:archivefetch cairo is installed with the following variants: +universal+x11
:debug:archivefetch   required: , forbidden: x11
:debug:archivefetch   rejected, because forbidden variant x11 is present
:error:archivefetch org.macports.archivefetch for port pango returned: cairo must be installed without +x11.
:debug:archivefetch Error code: NONE
:debug:archivefetch Backtrace: cairo must be installed without +x11.
    while executing
"$pre $targetname"
:info:archivefetch Warning: targets not executed for pango: org.macports.activate org.macports.archivefetch org.macports.fetch org.macports.checksum org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:error:archivefetch Failed to install pango
:debug:archivefetch couldn't open "/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tclIndex": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open [file join $dir tclIndex]"
:notice:archivefetch Please see the log file for port pango for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_pango/pango/main.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case (i.e. if you only want to run a few programs that aren't updated frequently), an app like [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) can wrap executables in their own Wine environment, avoiding the need to install Wine at the system level.

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

```
sudo port install cairo +universal -x11
sudo port install pango +universal
sudo port install cairo
```

After that, run 'sudo port install wine' again.